# Prevent Opera from adding "(#number)" to file name when I download files with existing name

Tags: browser, opera

Whenever I save a file from the Internet, Opera shows the download dialog and, if a file with the same name (as the file's default name) already exists in the default download location, it will automatically append a "(NUMBER)" (e.g (1), (2).. ) to the file name (it doesn't save it, but replaces the default name it shows with the appended one). Is there no way that I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: What version and OS of opera browser  are you using?

Comment: At the time I posted, I was probably on Windows 10 x64. However, the same occurs even now on Opera 53.0.2907.57 (stable), OS: Ubuntu 18.04 x64.